# MongoDB query using intersection of 2 lists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm working on a project where we use mongodb 4.4 as our database. The problem is I have to make a query that is too complicated using mongo query language.

That's an exemple of the data in the database:

```
{
    "neededQuantity": 100,
    "auth": {
        "groups": ["group-1"]
    },
    "createTime": "2022-02-03T14:17:25.809704600Z",
},
{
    "neededQuantity": 120,
    "auth": {
        "groups": ["group-3"]
    },
    "createTime": "2022-02-02T14:17:25.809704600Z",
},
{
    "neededQuantity": 150,
    "auth": {
        "groups": ["group-2","group-1"]
    },
    "createTime": "2022-02-01T14:17:25.809704600Z",
}
```

The query has to find the documents that have at least 1 element of the list auth.groups in common with an another list that is given as input.

If the input list is ["group-1"], the query result should be:

```
{
    "neededQuantity": 100,
    "auth": {
        "groups": ["group-1"]
    },
    "createTime": "2022-02-03T14:17:25.809704600Z",
},
{
    "neededQuantity": 150,
    "auth": {
        "groups": ["group-2","group-1"]
    },
    "createTime": "2022-02-01T14:17:25.809704600Z",
}
```

How can I do it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it with `$in`

```
db.collection.find({
    "auth.groups": {$in: ["group-1"]}
})
```

[playground](https://www.humongous.io/app/playground/mongodb/TCguR35i4rla)

more detail about $in [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)